# Расчет поворота овала по x,y

Tags: javascript, геометрия

У меня есть эллипс `x,y` этого эллипса и `x,y` точки куда этот эллипс должен смотреть нужно посчитать угол его поворота

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код. Надо видеть код. Мы ж даже не видим как вы отрисовываете. Это канвас, свгшки, изображения или что-то еще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Угол, на который необходимо повернуть объект, чтобы он смотрел на определенную точку, это один из двух компонентов [Полярной системы координат](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82)

Для перевода из [прямоугольной системы координат](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82) в полярную, а точнее для нахождения компонента угла, в `javascript`(и во многих других языках) есть функция `Math.atan2(y, x)`, она возвращает угол в радианах.

В итоге для Вашего случая, и принимая за 0 центр картинки, формула для расчета угла поворота будет примерно такая.

```
Math.atan2(y2, x2) - Math.atan2(y1, x1)
```

где  `x1 x2` координаты черной точки, а `x2 y2` координаты красной, с центром в центре эллипса.

```js
let rnd = () => Math.random()*180-90
let pts = [{x: rnd(), y: rnd()}, {x: rnd(), y: rnd()}];
let pts2 = [pts[0], {x: 0, y: 0}, pts[1]];
let line = d3.line().x(d => d.x).y(d => d.y) 
let path = d3.select('svg').append('path').datum(pts2).attr('d', line)
d3.select('text').html(calcAngle().toFixed(1))
d3.select('svg').selectAll('circle').data(pts).enter() .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', d => d.x).attr('cy', d => d.y).attr('r', 9)
  .style('cursor','pointer').call(d3.drag().on('drag', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
    path.attr('d', line)
    d3.select('text').html(calcAngle().toFixed(1))
  }))

function calcAngle(){
  let rad = Math.atan2(pts[1].y, pts[1].x) - 
            Math.atan2(pts[0].y, pts[0].x);
  return (rad / Math.PI * 180 + 360)%360;
}
```

```css
path, circle {
  fill:transparent;
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:2px;
}

circle:hover{
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="-100 -100 200 200" style="height:90vh;border:solid">
<text x=-90 y=-80></text>
</svg>
```